# Python Beautifulsoup : file.write(str) method get TypeError: write() argument must be str, not BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I wrote below codes:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys # where is the sys module in the source code folder ?

try:
    import urllib.request as urllib2 
except ImportError:
    import urllib2


print (sys.argv) # 
print(type(sys.argv)) # 

#baseUrl = "https://ecurep.mainz.de.xxx.com/ae5/"
baseUrl = "http://www.bing.com"
baseUrl = "http://www.sohu.com/"
print(baseUrl)

url = baseUrl 
page = urllib2.urlopen(url) #urlopen is a function, function is also an object
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), "html.parser") #NameError: name 'BeautifulSoup' is not defined

html_file = open("Output.html", "w")
soup_string = str(soup)
print(type(soup_string))
html_file.write(soup_string) # TypeError: write() argument must be str, not BeautifulSoup
html_file.close()
```

which compiler give below errors:

```
C:\hzg>py Py_logDownload2.py 1
['Py_logDownload2.py', '1']
<class 'list'>
http://www.sohu.com/
<class 'str'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Py_logDownload2.py", line 25, in <module>
    html_file.write(soup_string) # TypeError: write() argument must be str, not
BeautifulSoup
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\encodings\
cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 376-377:
 character maps to <undefined>
```

but soup_string is obviously a str, so why the first error given by compiler  ?
        also don't know why the second one appear.

what is more confusion,  if I change code to:

```
baseUrl = "https://ecurep.mainz.de.xxx.com/ae5/"
#baseUrl = "http://www.bing.com"
#baseUrl = "http://www.sohu.com/"
```

it will compile and have no error. (I have change the original name to "xxx").

Can anyone help to debug this?

**Update :**

I used to write Java codes and am a newbie for Python. With the help of you, I think I have made some progress with debugging Python: when debugging Java, always try to solve the first error; while in Python, ayways try to solve the last one.

Comment: You get a `UnicodeEncodeError`, not the `TypeError` you claim to get.

Comment: As @MartijnPieters said, you've got an encoding error, probably because the webpage you're trying to load contains some special characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to open your file with `utf-8`

```
import codecs
f = codecs.open("test", "w", "utf-8")
```

You can ignore the coding error (not recommended) by

```
f = codecs.open("test", "w", "utf-8", errors='ignore')
```

Comment: Yes it did work. Something about the debugging: I used to write Java codes and am a newbie for Python. With the help of you, I think I have made some progress with debugging Python: when debugging Java, always try to solve the first error; while in Python, ayways try to solve the last one. Right?

Comment: Maybe you didn't noitice this message in your traceback: _" (most recent call last)"_